Using Flutter/Dart, how do i create a text field where i can vary the line spacing exclusively between different lines of text displayed
I'm trying to create a custom text editor, where the spacing above and below a highlighted line of text can be changed, while the spacing for the rest of the text stays the same
I'm aware of the height property in the TextStyle widget but this applies to the entire text displayed
I've also tried adding a padding using a TextSpan/WidgetSpan widget but this only resulted in the textspan being misaligned with the default cursor position and the rest of the text

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
